# Proof of correlation coefficient

Tags: statistics

I was learning about correlation and linear regression.
In my book, $r$, the correlation coefficient, is defined as:

$$\frac{\text{Cov}(x,y)}{\sigma(x)\sigma(y)}$$
However, there's an assumption that the average of both $x$ and $y$ equals $0$. 
But I found that most of the time this is not the case. But the regression formulas are still used. Why is this so? Am i missing something? Or can anyone help to figure out how to proof this with non zero x and y value?
*[My book is David Morin's Probability for enthusiastic beginners]

Comment: In the definition of correlation coefficient, there's no assumption that $X$ and $Y$ have mean zero.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient